# MEF Export/ Import only if some external library satisfies

Tags: import, export, mef, dllimport

Is there a way to tell MEF to try to load a dll only if some other dependency dlls/ libraries are satisfied? I'm trying to write an extension that is dependent on another extension. I want to be able to check whether other extension exists or not than only try to load my extension. Is it even possible? I've already found out how to check whether certain dll exists or not by using following code (found somewhere on StackOverflow):

```
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string fileName);
        static bool CheckLibrary(string fileName)
        {
            return LoadLibrary(fileName) != IntPtr.Zero;
        }
```

Now I like to be able to load only those dlls/ extensions who have their dependency satisfied.

Comment: So you're saying that you have written an assembly that depends on a native DLL, and you want MEF to ignore this assembly if the native DLL is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MEF does this naturally through rejection.  Say you want extension A to load only if extension B is present.  Presumably this is because extension A depends on some functionality which extension B provides.  The way to express this in MEF is via an import (of cardinality ExactlyOne, ie not a collection import and not optional).

So extension A should have a required import which is satisfied by an export from extension B.  If extension B is not present, then the import will not be able to be satisfied, and extension A will be rejected, causing it to not be available in the container.

I explain a little more about this in my blog post: [How to Debug and Diagnose MEF Failures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2010/07/13/how-to-debug-and-diagnose-mef-failures.aspx).

Comment: Interesting! Never thought about importing the other extension. But what if I've no control over the other extension that I'm going to use? I mean say it doesn't export itself but only provides a service (an event) that I want to be able to subscribe to. Is there a way to handle such cases where I cannot simply 'IMPORT'?

Comment: @chown The extension doesn't have to export itself directly.  It can export a service (via implementing it or via a property export).  Or are you saying you don't have control over the code and can't add exports to that extension?